# Execute a document.ready in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need to run a script after a hook is fired in my functions.php file. Im using a wordpress mailchimp plugin, I need to do some text inserts and `display = "none"`, etc, in the html:

```
add_action( 'mc4wp_form_success', function() {
   // do something
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'console.log("starting....");', // this works
     'document.getElementById("mailchimp-is-subscribed").style.display = "none";',
         'document.getElementById("mailchimp-success-form").style.display = "block";',
         'console.log("end");',
     '</script>';
});
```

The error I got was `style` is `null`. I assume the document is not ready? `$` does not work. **Am I doing this wrong?** I need to run that code after that hook is called. Putting the code in `.js` file works great. Thanks

Comment: You are indeed doing this wrong. You can't just intermingle PHP and JavaScript like that.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah I thought so. What's the correct approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your code as an on DOMContentLoaded event:

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { ..your_code... }, false);`

Check this answer:  [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Comment: Sorry but that looks like half of jquery and I cant use jquery there.

Comment: SWEET! Works great but in this format `document.getElementById("mailchimp-is-subscribed").style.display = "none";` Thanks!